# Use values obtained from external class in HttpAsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, get

I am trying to use values which ​​I get from an external class in doInBackground method.

I had done everything in onCreate() but, what would be the right way to get those values?

Anyways, I can also accept other way to make the get request.

Here is my code:

```
    public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    cUserData ud = new cUserData(this); //This is my external class

    String email;

    String phone;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        ((myApp) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable(bundle.getString("email"));


        cUserData ud = new cUserData(this);

        String email= ud.getEmail; //I get the values from the external class

        String phone = ud.getTelephone();

        new HttpAsyncTask().execute();     
    }


    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String mEmail = email; //These values are null

            String mPhone = phone;

        String url = "http://www.myUrl.com/app/get.aspx?email=" + mEmail + "&telephone=" + mPhone;

            HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            try {

            Client.execute(httpget);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752274/passing-parameters-in-httpasynctask-execute

Comment: The ud.getEmail is a method that I call from another class.

Comment: public String getTelephone(){
       TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
       String context = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
       telephonyManager =     (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(context);
      String mPhoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
      return mPhoneNumber
    }   @Archie.bpgc

Comment: @imj Are you sure those functions return non-null values? because, `getLine1Number() Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.` The way you use them must ideally work, unless those functions run on a non-ui thread or they return null.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Yes, I tried with other values ​​(not only phone or e- mail), and I 've made sure that return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

cUserData ud = new cUserData(this); //This is my external class

String email;

String phone;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);



    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    ((myApp) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable(bundle.getString("email"));



    cUserData ud = new cUserData(this);

    String email= ud.getEmail; //I get the values from the external class

    String phone = ud.getTelephone();

    String mDataUrl ="www.myurl.com";
    mDataUrl += "?email="  + email;
    mDataUrl += "&telephone="  + phone;


    new HttpAsyncTask().execute(mDataUrl);     
}



private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return getData(urls[0]);
    }
}

public static String getData(String dataUrl){
//NOW I CAN USE VALUES
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass those values in the execute call like

```
HttpAsyncTask.execute(client);
```

then create a client class like

```
public class Client{
     public CLient(String email, String phNum){
        this.email = email;
        this.phNum = phNum;
     }
}
```

After this the AsyncTask would need to change slightly so that it extends AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use the AsyncTask like the following:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        ((LennyTracer) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable(bundle.getString("email"));

        new HttpAsyncTask().execute(new cUserData(this));
    }

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<cUserData, Void, String> {

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(cUserData[] cUserDatas) {

            String mEmail = cUserDatas.getEmail();

            String mPhone = cUserDatas.getTelephone();

            String url = "http://www.myUrl.com/app/get.aspx?email=" + mEmail + "&telephone=" + mPhone;

            HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            try {

                Client.execute(httpget);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;

        }

    }
}
```

However there are many libraries for async http requests which handle the process more efficiently. Take a look at those libraries:

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html